# Cordova Facebook Login - Login Error

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I want to create a Phonegap App with the Facebook Login Plugin (https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin).

I added Android as platform to the app on Facebook but when I try to login I get:

Login Error: There is an error logging you into this application. Please try again later.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Same error here, did you find a solution?

Comment: No solution found yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Found a "solution" even if the behaviour of the plugin looks strange to me. The login function doesn't test if a user is already logged in, so you must ALWAYS test if the user is already connected using the getconnectionstatus function.

Another strange behaviour is that the plugin seems to check if the user EVER used the Facebook application.

I used that Application from the web browser on a different computer, and from the device the plugin returned an active connection, even if I never used that app from that device.

Hope it helps.